# how to ensure requestLocationUpdates always gets a location?

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager, android-gps

i'm working with android's location manager, and i notice that when I try to use requestLocationUpdates right after I turn on GPS, it gives a null location. how do i ensure I always get a valid location when i call requestlocationupdates?

my code is:

```
            //update the location
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

            //get the location
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: Use the location from the `onLocationChanged()` callback, that's the only way to guarantee that you get a Location.  The `getLastKnownLocation()` method can and will return null.

Comment: @DanielNugent you should add as answer because it is right answer.